# How to respawn a sprite at certain y level unity, 2d, unity 5, linux

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to make it so when my sprite chuck square will respawn at an invisible empty object when he gets to y=-11 or more. I have tried to use a trigger with a collider but this seems to work better and if it doesn't please help me with box collider components and triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a player object with a box collider and a rigidbody if the collider he has attached to him bumps another colliser it will call

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

}
```

If the object’s collider its colliding with has ‘isTrigger’ selected then

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

}
```

is called

you can also sample the local transform, ie in a GameObject’s update loop call

```
if (transform.position.y < -11.0f) {

}
```